# What were the differences between the Sieges of Constantinople in 678, 717, and 1453, inc. Greek Fire?

Tags: byzantine-empire, ottoman-empire

Constantinople repelled the [sieges of 678](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Constantinople_%28674%E2%80%93678%29) and [717](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Constantinople_%28717%E2%80%93718%29) with Greek fire. What were the differences between the Byzantine army/navy in 678/717 versus 1453, and how did the Arab army/navy differ from the Ottoman army/navy?

Comment: Counterfactual; out of scope.  Speculation on alternative histories is discouraged.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "alternative history is not within the scope of this site"

Comment: In general, yes "would have ... if ... " questions are OT. However, the answer to this particular one is clear enough that I don't think there's going to be much argument about it. Both answers so far have the same conclusion.

Comment: What source do you have that they ever "forgot" Greek fire? It was still in use as far as I know, it simply isn't a wonder weapon and only has specific use cases.

Comment: I wasn't looking for counterfactual answers @MarkC.Wallace, I was looking for objective comparisons of the sieges of 678/717/1453, and the effect Greek Fire had on these sieges. T.E.D. made the strongest point that Mehmed's army wielded more fighting men than all of Constantinople.

Comment: It has befuddled me for a year or so @Alex why the first reaction on Stack Exchange is to downvote and close instead of making questions better.

Comment: @nobleuplift - because frequently it is very difficult to discern the intent of OP.  We have rules that are documented (see [ask]) and discussed (see meta), and when the question is explicitly out of scope, we vote to close.  per SE standard, we close, edit and re-open. That prevents people from answering questions that are under revision.  The question you originally asked required speculation about an alternative history in which Greek Fire had not been forgotten; that was a counterfactual.  Had I seen the current question, I would not VtC.

Comment: In fact, until 16 minutes ago, the question still requested a counterfactual; I feel less guilty about not spotting the edit.

Comment: I take responsibility for not logging into Stack Overflow in exactly a week so that I could repair the question in a timely manner. As for your second comment, are you referring to [Tom Au's revision](http://history.stackexchange.com/revisions/29011/3)?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at Mr. Au's revision; up until that revision, the question still asked whether X would have happened if Y had not happened. That is a counterfactual  - it is the study of an alternate history that did not happen. A fascinating question, but explicitly out of scope for H:SE. Mr. Au has revised the question to avoid that problem and I have nominated it for re-opening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Greek fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire) was used in naval warfare, a way to damage enemy ships.
[image]

The land sieges were ineffective in both cases.  In 1453 the Greeks had no navy, and not enough men to man the walls; but the Turks had great cannons -- they [battered the great walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople), and were able to climb over the weak points nearly unopposed.

So no, there was no secret weapon which could have saved Constantinople in 1453.

[image]

Comment: I was going to mention the canons, which featured prominently in the siege in everything I read years ago. However, it seems now there is a lot of doubt as to how important they were. Conclusion is still spot on though.

Comment: You are correct: cannons alone were not enough; the taking of the harbor of the Golden Horn was key, and it fell due to lack of manpower.  However, the cannons were very demoralizing for the defenders of the city.  See http://www.theottomans.org/english/campaigns_army/1453-the-conquest.asp

Answer (score 4):

Constantinople was doomed no matter what measures the defenders took.

The army Mehmed II sent against Constantinople probably had [more fighting men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople#Strength) in it than there were human beings (soldiers, residents, and refugees) in the city of Constantinople at the time. He owned all the land for hundreds of miles in either direction.

Essentially, the city had been reduced to a small fort within the Ottoman state. It really no longer had much reason to exist.

Secondly, its debatable that they had lost the knowledge for Greek Fire. Wikipedia is currently saying Greek Fire was used to collapse tunnels Mehmed's sappers were digging under the city during the siege. That claim appears to be sourced from [Rodger Crowley's 1453: The Holy War for Constantinople](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1401308503). Either way, it seems quite likely any supplies of it may have been quite limited due to the Greeks no longer controlling whatever territory its components were sourced from.